# JAX-RS and CDI / @Provider and beans.xml

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi

I made a simple project that makes use of JAX-RS (RESTfull service)

I have a JAX-RS (RESTfull service) webservice project that deploys to JBoss AS 6.1. resteasy integrated with JSON is provided by JBoss 6.1 AS by default. I wanted to change the date format of the default JSON resource.

I got some help from the Internet and added a class that extends `JacksonJsonProvider`:

- [Accessing Jackson Object Mapper in RestEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498413/accessing-jackson-object-mapper-in-resteasy)
- [Jersey + Jackson JSON date format serialization - how to change the format or use custom JacksonJsonProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428109/jersey-jackson-json-date-serialization-format-problem-how-to-change-the-form)

```java
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class MyJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    public static final String pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String,Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = locateMapper(type, mediaType);

        // Set customized date format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().setDateFormat(sdf);

        super.writeTo(value, type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    }
}
```

This works well until I added an empty beans.xml under WebContent/WEB-INF for CDI injection.

`MyJacksonJsonProvider` doesn't get called and I still get the default JSON date format.

Even adding the following dependency under pom.xml did not help:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have any idea why `MyJacksonJsonProvider` is ignored if I have an empty beans.xml under "WebContent/WEB-INF" folder? Thanks a lot in advance!

FYI, this is the sample model class:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "movie")
public class Movie {

    String name;
    String director;
    int year;
    Date date;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Date getDate() {
       return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

And this is the class that produces JSON resource:

```java
@Path("/json/movie")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Movie getMovieInJSON() {

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Little flower");
        movie.setDirector("Zhang Zheng");
        movie.setYear(1979);
        movie.setDate(new Date());

        return movie; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've run into this as well. It's a [known issue (RESTEASY-555)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-555), and the work-around, if you can't upgrade Resteasy to >= 2.3.3.Final, is to tell Weld to exclude `MyJacksonJsonProvider` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
                           http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">
  <weld:scan>
    <weld:exclude name="MyJacksonJsonProvider" />
  </weld:scan>
</beans>
```